# Segue in Navigation Controller Xcode 10

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I am a beginner in terms of coding in swift.

I use a navigation controller to navigate between different ViewControllers. On each ViewController I have buttons with IBOutlets connected to the ViewControllers to trigger a segue to go to the next ViewController.

**WHAT I WANT TO HAPPEN:** 
Inside of the IBOutlets I use the "perform segue with identifier" fuction to trigger the segue action only if the button was pressed.

**THE PROBLEM:**
The segue action always triggers two times.. so how can I disable the automatic segue action ?

Comment: If you control-dragged your Segue from the `UIButton` in the storyboard, *and* perform the segue as a programmatic action, it will trigger twice. I suggest you delete your segue in your storyboard, and then you ctrl+drag it from the *viewController* and not the button. Assign it a name, and trigger it programmatically as you did.

Comment: add segue with viewcontroller then call perform segue with identifier for segue action. What happening is one action of segue is done with button pressed and other programatically call be you.

Comment: Just so you know, because you are using a navigation controller, you don't need to worry about using segues, and you can just push viewControllers or pop them from the navigation stack. I can expand on that in an answer if you'd like.